# How to filter a value from the results in python S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I filter this specific piece of information? Attached my code. I would like to do print it like below & exclude other information.

Filename Object-Key Object-Value

```py
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.get_object_tagging(Bucket='xxx',  Key='xxx')

results = json.dumps(response, indent=1)
print(results)
print(type(results))
print(type(response))
print(response)
```

Output:

```json
...
 "TagSet": [
  {
   "Key": "deletion",
   "Value": "false"
  }
 ]
}
<class 'str'>
<class 'dict'>
...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to filter and print only the entry with key = 'deletion'?

Comment: Please do not post screenshot of your code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @ErvinSzilagyi for the article. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of the `get_object_tagging` is a dictionary. So you can print the `TagSet` as follows:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.get_object_tagging(
        Bucket='...',
        Key='...')

print(response['TagSet'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ervin. I was using the code like this, but yours is way easier!!!

import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
Name = "xxxx"
response = client.get_object_tagging(
        Bucket='...',
        Key='Name')
    tag_set = response.get("TagSet", [])
    tag_set = tag_set[0] if len(tag_set) else {}
    key = tag_set.get("Key", "")
    value = tag_set.get("Value", "")

    print(Name, key, value)